# Angular array update without complete refresh

Tags: arrays, angular

**Problem:**
There is an array e.g.

```
[{id: 1, name: "stefan"}, {id: 2, name: "alex"}, ...]
```

This list is bound to a `*ngFor` which can also show details.

Now there comes an update from the server with a new list

```
[{id: 1, name: "stefanie"}, {id: 2, name: "alexandra"}, ...]
```

So the `id`s are identical, but `name`s are the same.

**Requirement:**
Now if I want to assign the new array to the existing array, `*ngFor` gets completly refresh, hidding my details window. However I just want to

- update the item if one with the same `id` already exists
- add new items
- delete items which don't exist anymore

I found answers, how you can make this by filtering and updating, however it looks like a pretty common problem to me. So I guess there is alreay a build in function or a clever library which solves this... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the `TrackBy` feature of angular. With `TrackBy`, Angular is able to detect which items are deleted or added to an array, using a unique identifier. So, only the items added or removed have to be updated in the DOM.

[Here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5) is an extended explanation of `TrackBy`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ***ngFor with trackBy** see [this example](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor-with-trackby).